# Proc Sql Output

Tags: sql, sas

Hello i am new in sas and i created sql code, and now i need to redirect the output to /tmp/output.txt.

```
proc sql;
select (COUNT(IDCUENTACLIENTE)) AS COUNT_of_IDCUENTACLIENTE from  S1.CUENTACLIENTE  where segmentonivel1  = 'Altas Recientes'
and segmentonivel2 = 'Masivo'
GROUP BY SEGMENTONIVEL1,SEGMENTONIVEL2;
quit;
```

I tried to put

```
data _null_;
  FILE "/tmp/MyFile.txt";
run;
```

but is not creating the file.

Some one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have a sugestion...
First create a data set using the query. In your code, I have doubts about the GROUP BY you are using. It's run without errors?
Second export to txt file like below

```
proc sql;
   create table work.temp as 
   select SEGMENTONIVEL1,SEGMENTONIVEL2, (COUNT(IDCUENTACLIENTE)) AS  
    COUNT_of_IDCUENTACLIENTE from  S1.CUENTACLIENTE  
   where segmentonivel1  = 'Altas Recientes'
   and segmentonivel2 = 'Masivo'
   GROUP BY SEGMENTONIVEL1,SEGMENTONIVEL2;
quit;
/* code to create TXT file  */
data _null_;
  FILE "/tmp/MyFile.txt";
  set work.temp;
  put 
     SEGMENTONIVEL1
     SEGMENTONIVEL2
     COUNT_of_IDCUENTACLIENTE;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use the filename definition and you don't want to write the filename into datastep:

```
proc sql;
    create table tableName as
        select (COUNT(IDCUENTACLIENTE)) AS COUNT_of_IDCUENTACLIENTE from  
        S1.CUENTACLIENTE  where segmentonivel1  = 'Altas Recientes'
            and segmentonivel2 = 'Masivo'
        GROUP BY SEGMENTONIVEL1,SEGMENTONIVEL2;
quit;

filename x "c:\temp\teszt.txt";

data _null_;
 file x;
 set work.tableName;
 put COUNT_of_IDCUENTACLIENTE;
run;
```